# Return day of the week from int 1-7

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using `moment.js` how to return day of the week?

I have tried the following:

```
var i = 3;
moment(i).format('dddd');
```

Expected to return Wednesday which it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to let Moment know what the input format is. In your case, the input format is the day of the week, which Moment defines as `'e'` or `'E'` depending on whether you're wanting it 0-indexed or not:

```
moment(i, 'e').format('dddd') // if 0-6
moment(i, 'E').format('dddd') // if 1-7
```

> ```
> Input Example Description
> e     0..6    Locale day of week
> E     1..7    ISO day of week
> ```
>
> – Moment's documentation on [Week year, week, and weekday tokens](http://momentjs.com/docs/#week-year-week-and-weekday-tokens).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `moment.weekdays()`, see example below, but please check out James Donnelly answer as well.

```js
var weekdayInt = 3
var weekdays = moment.weekdays()
document.write(weekdays[weekdayInt])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```